# Does Xamarin support Google Calendar API

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to develop a Xamarin. Form app that allows me to display Google Calendar(Google.Apis.Calendar.v3) in the app, is it possible? Because I can't find a definite answer [Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzrJo.png)

Comment: Since this API is REST-based, I don't see why you couldn't. You might not find a library to abstract the REST part, but that just means a little more work, since Xamarin should be able to make HTTP requests while specifying the verb.

Comment: The `Google.Apis.Calendar.v3` Client .Net package lists Xamarin under its "Incompatible platforms" list. But as @Sidewinder94 stated, you can use the underlying REST api directly ( https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/ )

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I added an example of how I want the calendar in my app to look like, since I am actually quite new to programming, can I just check if it is possible to  do it?

Comment: Short answer, yes.  Long answer, if may be a lot of work if you want to have a custom UI and you are not very experienced.

Comment: You can mark/upvote the answer if it helps you:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the Google Calendar api is a rest api meaning that you can use it with any language caplable of doing a http post or http get.

I think the question you are really asking is if Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 (which is part of the [Google .net client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client)) supports Xamarin.

The answer is a little complicated.  While Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 would support it the google.apis.auth does not support Xamarin.  which would mean that you would need to use Xamarin to create your auth and then have that then create a credential object that Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 could then read.

I have done it in the past it is doable but like i said you need to do the auth yourself the library does not support Xamarin and there is no intention to support it in the future
[Please support Xamarin Forms! #1391](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1391)